# close pipe from parent and child process

Tags: c, pipe, fork

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    int p[2];
    pipe(p);
    if (fork() == 0) {
        // child
/*#0*/  close(p[1]);
        int received = -1;
        while (read(p[0], &received, 4) != 0) {
            printf("receive integer: %d\n", received);
            received = -1;
        }
        printf("child exit\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        // parent
/*#1*/  close(p[0]);

        int sent = 42;
        write(p[1], &sent, 4);
/*#2*/  close(p[1]);
        printf("wait for child\n");

        wait(0);
    }

    printf("finished\n");
}
```

I'm trying to understand `fork` and `pipe` in C. This program fork a child process, which receive an integer from parent process then exit when pipe closed. When executing, it prints

```
wait for child
receive integer: 42
child exit
finished
```

Yet the while loop got stuck after `close(p[1]);` at position `#0` removed: that `read` would infinitely wait for an incoming variable from the pipe and never detect the pipe closed.

Can someone explain to me why `p[1]` has to be closed by both parent (position `#2`) and child (position `#0`) process?

Comment: Because that's how it works.  All of the write sides of a pipe need to be closed before the pipe is closed.   The system is not going to detect this race condition for you; if you are blocked on yourself, it's your bug to fix.

Comment: BTW, you should replace `4` with either `sizeof sent` or `sizeof received` or `sizeof(int)` (preferably the first 2).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code (from Linux manual page) with comments at the bottom of the code.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html

At /*#2*/ close(pipefd[1]), the comment states that "Reader will see EOF". It means there is nothing to read into child process anymore and then the statement "read(p[0], &received, 4)" will return 0. In the Linux manaul page https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html
states that "On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file)"

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int pipefd[2];
       pid_t cpid;
       char buf;

       if (argc != 2) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
           perror("pipe");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       cpid = fork();
       if (cpid == -1) {
           perror("fork");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child reads from pipe */
           close(pipefd[1]);          /* Close unused write end */

           while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
               write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);

           write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
           close(pipefd[0]);
           _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

       } else {/* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
           close(pipefd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
           write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
 /*#2*/    close(pipefd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
           wait(NULL);                /* Wait for child */
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
   }
```